# Rewrite rule mandando para página errada

Tags: htaccess, url-rewrite

Tenho as seguintes `rewrites` no meu `htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^dados/series/([a-z,0-9,A-Z-].+)/?$ dados-series.php?cache=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^dados/series/([a-z,0-9,A-Z-].+)/configs/?$ serie-configs.php?serie=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Mas por algum motivo, a rewrite que deveria ser lida na página `serie-configs` está sendo mandada para a primeira página, no caso `dados-series`, o que poderia estar causando tal erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teu *"grupo"* de `[a-z,0-9,A-Z-]` não faz sentido e o uso de `.+` toda o que esta dentro de `[...]` quase redundante, tem que aprender primeiro regex antes de sair fazendo qualquer coisa amigo, sem querer soar mal, mas tem muitos exemplo no site, principalmente sobre regex, veja [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) e [htaccess](/questions/tagged/htaccess)

As virgulas dentro do `[]` parece que você usou como separador, mas em regex isso **não** existe, o `-` dentro `[]` deve ser "escapado" com barra `\`.

O sinal de ponto `.` é o que causou a falha, isto porque o ponto é um meta-caractere que "casa" com qualquer caractere, veja o que ocorre:

- Veja no exemplo https://regex101.com/r/rHb1DH/4/

  O seu regex pega todas as linhas, com `configs` e sem na string

Agora se ajustar:

- Veja no exemplo https://regex101.com/r/rHb1DH/5/

  O regex correto só pega as duas linhas que não contém `configs`

Então ajuste para isto:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dados/series/([a-z0-9A-Z\-]+)/?$ dados-series.php?cache=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^dados/series/([a-z0-9A-Z\-]+)/configs/?$ serie-configs.php?serie=$1 [NC,L]
```

E se ainda não funcionar inverta a ordem:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dados/series/([a-z0-9A-Z\-]+)/configs/?$ serie-configs.php?serie=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^dados/series/([a-z0-9A-Z\-]+)/?$ dados-series.php?cache=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note que se as urls forem relativas aos documentos internos então não necessita de `rewritebase`, usá-lo pode causar acidendetes, também retirei o `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` porque do meu ponto de vista se o módulo não estiver ativado mesmo com IF o site vai falhar porque os links acusarão que não existem, então é melhor que de *erro 500* ao invés da pessoa acessar páginas quebradas

Comment: Estou tentando aprender regex, por isso estou testando de diversas formas, obrigado pelas sugestões.